# Unable to delete Instance Groups

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am using the Free tier GCP for learning purposes. I created a few instance groups in the process. When I try to delete them, all are stuck for different reasons. Eg. a few are stuck saying: `Exceed limit 'Quota_for_instances'on resource`. A few are stuck with message that says the instance group is in use by some backend service. I have removed those linkages. But this deletion process of instance groups is just hung and the entries are also disabled.
[image: Attaching a screenshot]

Comment: If you use this project for  learning purposes only why don't you delete the project to start from scratch with a new one?

Comment: Yes, i am going to try exactly that..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the instance will not update the status until you refresh the page, if you see at the top of the page you will see an option to refresh the VM instances page. If this behavior persist and you internet connection is stable I recommend you to open a case with GCP support team.

Regarding the error you show is indicating you have reached instance quota limit, please review the limit details for free trial accounts.

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits

I hope this information be helpful to you.